# Soundcloud API query for tags by hotness and created after

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to get the `JSON` for the following `soundcloud` track listing page.

```
http://soundcloud.com/tags/Hiphop
```

The query I try to perform is

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?order=hotness&limit=20&created_at[from]=2012-05-18&tags=hiphop + consumer key.
```

All of the songs on that tags page are less than 3 days old, and I am ordering by hotness. The filters doesn't seem to work at all. The results of the query and the `tags/Hiphop` page are not even close. Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't seem to get the filters to work either. They must be down or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the created_at filter cannot be used with the order parameter. If you'd like to replicate the listing in the URL you provided, just make the following API request:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&tags=hiphop&order=hotness
```

Or, in JavaScript, assuming you have a ul element with an id 'tracks':

```
var url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&tags=Hiphop&order_by=hotness';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, track) {
        $('<li />', { text: track.title }).appendTo('#tracks');                    
    });
});
```

Comment: Hotness is now deprecated :( https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param